# Insert data from form to database

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

What i want to do is next:

1. Create simple form with FormBuilder
2. When form is submitted the result to be saved into database for particular user ( based on its ID )

In addition is the code from the controller:

```
public function helloAction(Request $request, $id){//displaying individual results for particular user//


// find the username which was in the view//

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT b FROM AcmeWebBundle:baza b WHERE b.id = :id' )
        ->setParameter('id',$id);
        $total = $query->getResult();  

$baza = new baza ();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($baza);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($baza) 
                    ->add ('rating','choice',array('label'=>'TEST44','choices'=>array(
                        '1'=>'1',
                        '2'=>'2',
                        '3'=>'3',
                        '4'=>'4'
                        ),

                    'expanded'=>true,
                    'multiple'=>false
                    ))
                    ->getForm();


        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
                $em->flush();

                return new Response('<h1>THANKS FOR Your feedback !!!!</h1>');

            }


        }


return $this->render('AcmeWebBundle:Default:hello.html.twig',array('all'=>$total,'id'=>$id ,'form'=>$form->createView()));
}
}
```

But this creates new row in the database, and add value only for the rating column.Moreover, id field,username and etc.. are empty.

What i want to do is, rating to be added for the colum rating, but for specific ID.

Comment: Do you call `$em->persist($baza)` on every 'GET' request? You must clear your mind a reorganize your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example I create a form, get the data on `POST` and then persist the fresh object or a modified one, there is no point in persisting an empty object.

```
public function historialAction(Request $request)
{
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('phone', 'text', array('attr' => array('autofocus' => '')))
->add('period', 'number', array('attr' => array('value' => '12')))
->getForm();

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);

    // data is an array with "phone" and "period" keys
    $data = $form->getData();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $contract = $em->getRepository('FrontBundle:Contract')->getContractByPhone($data["phone"]);
    $contract->setOwner("John Doe");
    $contract->setPhone($data["phone"]);

    // or this could be $contract = new Contract("John Doe", $data["phone"], $data["period"]);


    $em->persist($contract); // I set/modify the properties then persist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the rating to the user entity like so..

```
if ($form->isValid())
    $rating = $form->get('rating')->getData();
    $user->setRating($rating);
    // Assuming $user is the user entity

    // etc..
```